# I'm making a countdown for android, but I can't realize how to create it

Tags: java, android

```
Date lol = c.getTime();
long milli_now = lol.getTime();
c.set(2013, c.MAY, 21);             
Date lol1 = c.getTime();                
long milli_then = lol1.getTime();               
long milli_tot = (milli_then - milli_now);              
long sec = (milli_tot/1000);
long min = 0;
long hour = 0;
min = (sec/60);
days.setText("Days left: " + (sec/60/60/24));
countdown.setText(""+hour+":"+min+":"+sec);
```

What should I do to have it like 216 hours, 60 mins, 60 secs?

I can't figure out the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

```
long totDiff = (lastDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime());      // Total differance in milliseconds
long Sdiff = (totDiff / 1000) % 60;                             // Differance in seconds
long Mdiff = (totDiff / (60 * 1000)) %60;                       // Differance in minutes
long Hdiff = (totDiff / (60 * 60 * 1000));                      // Remaining time in hours
```

This should give you the output you're looking for.

Comment: actually it doesn't, it gives me 192 hrs, 0 minutes and 0 secs

Comment: ok, that was right, i made it count down, the error i was refferring to is that (and i didn't resolve it yet) it always starts from 59 mins and 59 secs, only the hours are decreasing, at every start of the app, the mins and secs starts from 59, always

Comment: Ok, I guess that's not a math problem :p You would have to show me more of your code if I am supposed to help you.

Comment: @DomeWTF If my answer answered your question please mark it as such :)

Comment: Weird. Looks fine to me. Implemented an [example in javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/w3xJg/) which seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

What are you getting with this code? As far as I can tell, the only thing you're missing is

```
hour = min / 60;
```

Comment: i'm getting 216 hours, corrisponding minutes and seconds, but i cannot have 248645 seconds, i want it to be max 60 as for mins